# The number of rolls of $6$ dice with exactly $4$ distinct values.

Tags: combinatorics, dice

I know the answer is $${6 \choose 4}{5 \choose 3}$$ However, I don't understand why this is true?

Answer (score 0):

The binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$ is exactly the number of possible choices of $k$ elements in a set with $n$ elements.

The rolls of $6$ dice with exactly $4$ distinct values are constructed as follows:

- Choose the $4$ distinct values among the $6$ possible, this gives you a factor $\binom{6}{4}$.
- Partition your set of dice into $4$ nonempty subsets (one for each value). Since the dice are undistinguishable, this is equivalent to put $3$ separations between elements, choosing between $5$ possible places to put such a separation gives you a factor $\binom{5}{3}$.

An example of such a separation cited above (stars represent dice):
$$**|*|**|*$$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, what if the dices are 1,2,3,4,5,6 sided dice respectively? You mentioned the dice are indistinguishable, I'm wondering what if they are instead.

Comment: @whatdidthefoxsay The fact that they are indistinguishable means that if we mark the dice, then a throw is considered the same as the same throw exchanging two dice, e.g. the throw $1,1,2,4,4,5$ is the same as the throw $2,1,1,5,4,4$. If you change the number of faces of the dice, then everithing changes. You can try and work it out by yourself.